# rails redirect or render with a specific verb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, http-verbs

I want to redirect to a resource index when a new item is created

Here is a piece of the controller:

```
def create
    @asset = Asset.new(params[:asset])
    @assets = Asset.all
    respond_to do |format|
      if @asset.save
        format.html { render :action => 'index' } ##########
        format.xml  { render :xml => @asset, :status => :created, :location => @asset }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @asset.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The line i'm interested is marked ##########

i've tried

```
  format.html { redirect_to(assets_url) }
```

and some other stuff

It redirects to the right place and creates the item fine, the problem is that i cant get it to not `POST`. I need to get it to `GET` because otherwise it does some horribly screwy things to my view.

Answer (score 0):

`redirect_to :action => :index` Or `redirect_to assets_url` should work for you. Also, `index` action is always `GET` request. Do `rake routes` to see what kind of request happens for each action in your controller.